# Export Paw endpoints to Postman

Tags: postman, paw-app

My team and I use Postman when we work on a project with a REST server.

I'm generally the one that builds out the REST server and has all the requests mapped in Postman which I export the collection and commit it in git so the rest of the team stays up-to-date and can do their own tests whilst developing the clients to consume the REST server.

I have been looking at PAW for a while and I have two questions:

1. Can you create a project and share it with a team which it syncs to everyone on the project OR can you export a project and put it in git which the team can import updates to stay up-to-date?
2. As I'm not sure if everyone in the team will out lay the money to buy the app, can you export from Paw and import into Postman?

Thanks

Comment: There's no way to export all requests to Postman, as Export/Code Generators are only on a per request basis. For now sync can be done via Git or Dropbox, by simply sharing the .paw file. Anywyas in the next big version seamless sharing should be added, as well as batch export to Postman, Swagger, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In response to:

> As I'm not sure if everyone in the team will out lay the money to buy the app, can you export from Paw and import into Postman?

You can import your Paw requests into Postman using cURL requests.

Just make sure to grab the [cURL Code Generator](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/?q=curl) from the Paw Extension page, and export your cURL Request.

Then import it into Postman as shown: 
[image: Postman Import]

Comment: This did not work for me. Copy/Pasting the Paw cURL output... Postman gave an error saying "Error while importing Curl: Zero or Multiple option-less arguments. Only one is supported (the URL)."

Comment: @DirtyBirdNJ I had to take out the new lines and escape characters (\) to get past the "Error while import Curl" -- imported perfectly after that.

Answer (score 3):

**Export from Paw:**

`File -> Export All Requests ->`

You get presented a short list of already installed exporters followed by the section `Available Online` showing more export formats. Choose `Postman 2.0`. The plugin is installed on-the-fly and a JSON file is exported.

**Import to Postman:**

`Import -> Import File ->`

Drag exported JSON file into import window.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not too late, you can now do all of the above using Postman Cloud.

https://www.getpostman.com/plans/cloud-basic

Comment: Can you export from Paw to Postman using postman cloud? I don't think so.